# MySQL LIKE operator isn't working as expected for pattern matching

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

I'm given a relational table **`STATION`** as given below:

```
+------+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
| ID   | CITY           | STATE | LAT_N | LONG_W |
+------+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
|  794 | Kissee Mills   | MO    |   140 |     73 |
|  824 | Loma Mar       | CA    |    49 |    131 |
|  603 | Sandy Hook     | CT    |    72 |    148 |
|  478 | Tipton         | IN    |    34 |     98 |
|  619 | Arlington      | CO    |    75 |     93 |
|  711 | Turner         | AR    |    50 |    101 |
|  839 | Slidell        | LA    |    85 |    152 |
|  342 | Chignik Lagoon | AK    |   103 |    153 |
+------+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
```

and I'm required to perform a query which is:

> Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION.

I'm using MySQL version 5.7 on Ubuntu OS.

Now, here's my attempt:

```sql
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LOWER(CITY) LIKE '[aeiou]%';
```

But this **doesn't** yield the required result. I'm getting an empty set as the output. However, this is working just fine:

```sql
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LOWER(CITY) REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```

I'm wondering what's wrong in the first method with `LIKE` operator, any idea? I'm new to SQL so please excuse me if I've done something silly.

*Thank you for your time.*

Comment: Could you not simply do `where lower(left(city,1)) in ('a', 'e' ,'i', 'o', 'u')`?

Comment: @Gandalf I wasn't really concerned about getting the correct solution because I already had one using regex (as given in method 2). I was just curious why method1 wasn't working which the answers given below explained well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` and `REGEXP` do not follow the same rules for pattern matching. `REGEXP` supports regular expressions, while `LIKE` understands wildcards `'_'` (a single character) and `'%'` (an arbitrary number of characters, including no characters at all).

This is well explained in [the pattern matching documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use _ to match any single character and % to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters). In MySQL, SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default. Some examples are shown here. Do not use = or <> when you use SQL patterns. Use the LIKE or NOT LIKE comparison operators instead.
>
> [...]
>
> The other type of pattern matching provided by MySQL uses extended regular expressions. When you test for a match for this type of pattern, use the REGEXP_LIKE() function (or the REGEXP or RLIKE operators, which are synonyms for REGEXP_LIKE()).

Side note: both pattern matching methods are case-insensitive by default (unless you use some special collations), so you regex could possibly be simplified to not use the `lower()` function:

```
city like regexp '^[aeiou]'
```

If you were to express this with `like`, that would be:

```
city like 'a%' 
or city like 'e%'
or city like 'i%'
or city like 'o%'
or city like 'u%'
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` in MySQL does not support wildcards.  You can do something similar with regular expressions:

```
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LOWER(CITY) REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```